ffmpeg will not work in a bat file but will work if pasted into cmd
if I start the following code by pasting it in cmd or powershell it works fine.
@echo off
C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="CC1" -vf "fps=0.5,drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='%{localtime}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1:fontsize=30" -q:v 2 -t 9 "C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frame%03d.jpg"

but if I make a batch file camera1.bat or camera1.cmd and double click it it will not work , it says
[image2 @ 0000019fc1833c40] The specified filename 'C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frameC:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\camera1.bat3d.jpg' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
[image2 @ 0000019fc1833c40] Use a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.
[image2 @ 0000019fc1833c40] Could not open file : C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frameC:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\camera1.bat3d.jpg
[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 0000019fc1834580] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: I/O error
    Last message repeated 1 times
[out#0/image2 @ 0000019fc1823840] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/image2 @ 0000019fc1823840] Task finished with error code: -5 (I/O error)
[out#0/image2 @ 0000019fc1823840] Terminating thread with return code -5 (I/O error)

Does anyone know how to fix this?
updated bat
C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="CC!" -vf "fps=0.5,drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='%%{localtime}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1:fontsize=30" -q:v 2 -t 9 "C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frame%03d.jpg"

error
[image2 @ 0000024031943cc0] The specified filename 'C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frameC:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\camera1.bat3d.jpg' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
[image2 @ 0000024031943cc0] Use a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.
[image2 @ 0000024031943cc0] Could not open file : C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frameC:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\camera1.bat3d.jpg
[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 0000024031944540] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: I/O error
    Last message repeated 1 times
[out#0/image2 @ 0000024031943bc0] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/image2 @ 0000024031943bc0] Task finished with error code: -5 (I/O error)
[out#0/image2 @ 0000024031943bc0] Terminating thread with return code -5 (I/O error)
[out#0/image2 @ 0000024031943bc0] video:37KiB audio:0KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: unknown
frame=    1 fps=0.3 q=2.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.592x
Conversion failed!


Showing the output from CMD showing the command would also be helpful. This will show the command that is actually executed, and you will see where CMD removed or replaced the % characters.

Please also [edit] the question to see how to format a code block (two ways) and how to use inline code like I used for the script names camera1.bat. If you don't want to change anything, you can press Cancel to leave the editing.

The script contains
"C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frame%03d.jpg"

In the error message you can see the resulting file name
'C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frameC:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\camera1.bat3d.jpg'

Inside a script, CMD replaces %0 with the script name, which apparently is 
C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\camera1.bat
Replace the % with %% in the file name pattern:
"C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frame%%03d.jpg"

When the code is pasted into a CMD window, the variable %0 is not defined, and CMD will leave it as it is.

In the modified command, the % was doubled in text='%{localtime}', but not in the file name "C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frame%03d.jpg" as shown above. It must be doubled at both places.
C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="CC1" -vf "fps=0.5,drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='%%{localtime}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1:fontsize=30" -q:v 2 -t 9 "C:\Users\sohba\Downloads\0ffmpeg\t1\frame%%03d.jpg"


Thanks but that didnt work. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks

ok added it to question

Its working now, I missed one of the %, not just in frame%%03d.jpg but missed  %%{localtime}' Thanks

yes I see, I just need to get the hang of it. accepted , thanks
